# How to Remove +new document for specific document library in SharePoint-2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, powershell

I need power shell script to Remove the +new document and drag drop option for specific document library with full permission?

Comment: Is there a reason for giving full permission when you do not actually want users to have full permissions? There are myriad ways to upload a document. Just disabling UI features isn't going to be enough if you're trying to prevent uploads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the `+ new document and drag drop option` for specific document library via CSS by doing the following

- Open Document Library > Edit Page.
- Add Script Editor

Add the following CSS Style

```
<style>
#Hero-WPQ2 {

display: none ! important;
}
</style>
```

**[Update]**

To disable drag and drop functionality, check [Hide and Disable + new document and drag files option in Document Library in SharePoint 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/09/15/hide-disable-new-doc-drag-drop-files-document-library-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: Great, But We need to disable the drag and drop functionalities for specific document library @Qassas

Comment: @SuriyaadevanBalu now, you can't make drag and drop it's hidden ?  should you tell me how you can now drag and drop ?

Comment: I hope we are just hiding the element,I simply drag the file into the document library its uploaded,Content area fully considered as Drop zone @Qassas

Comment: @SuriyaadevanBalu Please check the updated answer. I wrote the attached article in details  to disable drag and drop functionality , hope it helped you, please don't hesitate to tell me if you need more clarification